# How to use variables inside a select (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, select

If I want to compute a column and use the result in more than 1 column, how do I do this without making the computing twice?

Example:

```
SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING([NAME], 4, 100)) + '@somedomain.com' as EMail
      ,hashbytes('SHA1', LOWER(SUBSTRING([NAME], 4, 100)) + '@somedomain.com') as HashedEmail
FROM sometable
```

How do I avoid writing this twice without using more than one select?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Derived table

```
SELECT
    EMail,
    hashbytes('SHA1', EMail) AS HashedEmail
FROM
    (
    SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING([NAME], 4, 100)) + '@somedomain.com' as EMail
    FROM sometable
   ) foo
```

or CTE:

```
;WITH cEMail AS
(
    SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING([NAME], 4, 100)) + '@somedomain.com' as EMail
    FROM sometable
)
SELECT
    EMail,
    hashbytes('SHA1', EMail) AS HashedEmail
FROM
    cEMail
```

However, in this case I'd consider using a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) with the hash precalculated

Comment: As long as the domain is static and dynamic per-request, the computer column is a terrific idea.

Answer (score 3):

First, I think you wanted to write hashbytes instead of haststring. hashstring is no SQL function.

Here is the code that will give you want you want I hope.

```
DECLARE @yourvariable nvarchar (50) =  '@somedomain.com';

SELECT LOWER(SUBSTRING([NAME], 4, 100)) + @yourvariable  as EMail
      ,HashBytes('SHA1', LOWER(SUBSTRING([NAME], 4, 100)) +  @yourvariable) as HashedEmail 
FROM sometable;
```